# Graphical glitches in Nano when using ssh

Tags: nano

I have Windows 10 and I'm using ssh in powershell. Nano editor is very glitchy though, when I'm writing something, the cursor suddenly jumps at random places (especially to the rightmost place at the end of the line, even if the line doesn't contain any characters), adds long lines of "empty strings". The navigation then seems glitchy as well - arrow keys do not move me to the left/right/up/down, but seemingly randomly.

Detailed example:
When I wrote "delitel" and pressed spacebar, the cursor for seemingly no reason moves to the right (I pressed g so you see where the cursor is):[image]

Pressing left key like 4 times moves me 4 times to the left, but pressing it for the fifth time moves me to the beginning of the left line. When I navigate to the letter "l" and press the right arrow **once**, it moves me to g immediatelly. Trying to delete this space only produces further graphical glitches.

How to resolve this please?

Comment: what is TERM set to in that ssh session? `echo $TERM`

Comment: Try running `TERM=rxvt nano [...]`, this fixes the issues atleast on my WSL

Comment: The TERM is xterm-256color. Panki can you be more specific please, typing "TERM=rxvt nano" into command line says "-bash: xterm-256color: command not found"

Comment: @Lisse-Etale-Site are you sure you typed `TERM=[...]` and not `$TERM=[...]`?

Comment: Ah I typed "TERM = rxvt nano" (with the spacebars), that's why it didn't work. Seems to kinda work allright but there are question marks everywhere now. https://i.imgur.com/LhAsueA.png